# Is there any way to make a json key a field in redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, jsonpath

I basically want to obtain all of the keys within "questions" and make individual records for each key.
Say I have json data that looks something like this:

```
"result": {
    "id": "dsgdsg",
    "name": "xxx",
    "expiration": {
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null
    },
    "questions": {
        "QID4": {
            "questionType": {
                "selector": "TB",
                "subSelector": null
            },
            "questionLabel": null,
            "validation": {
                "doesForceResponse": false
            }
        },
        "QID5": {
            "questionType": {
                "selector": "ML",
                "subSelector": null
            },
            "questionLabel": null,
            "validation": {
                "doesForceResponse": false
            }
        },
        "QID6": {
            "questionType": {
                "selector": "SAVR",
                "subSelector": "TX"
            },
            "questionLabel": null,
            "validation": {
                "doesForceResponse": false
            }

        },
        "QID7": {
            "questionType": {
                "selector": "SAVR",
                "subSelector": "TX"
            },
            "questionLabel": null,
            "validation": {
                "doesForceResponse": false
            }

        }

    }
    }
```

would there be any way using jsonpaths to individually load each QID into its own field with its own record? I have tried something on the lines of this:

```
    {
"jsonpaths": [
    "$.result.id",
    "$.result.name",
    "$.result.questions.[0]"
]
}
```

but this only gives the data within QID4 and so on. Could i somehow loop through the jsonpaths?

Comment: Are there a fixed number of questions in every result...i.e. all results have questions 4-7?

Comment: No, that is my main problem every result has a different number of questions so I cannot give a concrete number min and max.

Comment: What I am trying to do now is basically use python to get all of the qids and create a new field within the qid which contains that key.

Comment: Two step approach? 1. Copy entire JSON as VARCHAR to one column, and 2. Write a UDF to extract fields as you like.

Comment: @rohitvk I have never tried using UDFs I am currently researching, if you have any documentation that is close to what I am trying to do, please link me. Thank you very much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Would be best if you can change it on the Python side so each JSON record is one question with the result information included in each if needed. With jsonpaths the data file is not actually valid JSON. It's made up of separate JSON blobs, one for each record.

An example of two such records based on your data would be:

```
{
    "qid" : "QID4",  "result_id" : "dsgdsg", "result_name": "xxx",
    "result_expiration": { "result_startDate": null, "result_endDate": null },
    "questionType": { "selector": "TB", "subSelector": null },
    "questionLabel": null,
    "validation": { "doesForceResponse": false }
}
{
    "qid" : "QID5",  "result_id" : "dsgdsg", "result_name": "xxx",
    "result_expiration": { "result_startDate": null, "result_endDate": null },
    "questionType": { "selector": "ML", "subSelector": null },
    "questionLabel": null,
    "validation": { "doesForceResponse": false }
}
```

Note that there's no comma between the two records.

Then jsonpaths would be like:

```
{
"jsonpaths": [
    "$.qid",
    "$.result_name",
    "$.result_expiration.result_startDate",
    ...
]
}
```

If that's not feasible there may be an approach where you could load the whole "$.result.questions" element into a field in a staging/temporary table as JSON and manipulate it with [Redshift JSON functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) into a final table.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think the first example may not be possible. I already have loaded the questions into one column within redshift I will look into the redshift json functions you provided. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Actually do you think that I could go through the data in python and create a new field like this for example:
      "questions": {
        "QID4": {
            "questionType": {
                "selector": "TB",
                "subSelector": null
            },
            "qid":QID4,
            "questionLabel": null,
            "validation": {
                "doesForceResponse": false
            }
where i append that QID 4 into the current question set?

Comment: I think I see where you're going with that. It could work if each record in the JSON is one of the questions. You just need the "QUID4" as a value in there instead of a key name so it can go into a table column. You don't need any of the result header data?